# chart js graficos dinamicos

Tags: jquery, json, chart.js

Buenas tardes comunidad.
soy un novato en el desarrollo web y necesito realizar una graficas dinamicas utilizando la libreria chart js, Utilizo un función en java script, que utiliza un método estático para consultar al servidor, obteniendo como respuesta un DataSet con varias tablas sereializado como objeto JSON.

```
(string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_dsCon);)
```

y lo retorno de esta forma a la funcion JavaScript, ya en la funcion JavaScript convierto esta respuesta a formato JSON

```
(var json = JSON.parse(resultado.d))
```

Ahora necesito organizar dicho JSON de forma que pueda enviarlo a la función y que me lo reconozca para que pueda pintar la gráfica.

Hasta ahora solo obtengo respuesta del servidor de datos y en la parte del cliente no he avanzado nada, necesito su ayuda, muchas gracias.

mi json seria algo así, el date set que serializo, puede traer varias tablas y el nombre de la seria seria la propiedad que tiene como alias C019NomMaestro:

```
{
"Table": [{
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 4,
    "C019Dia": 21,
    "C019Horas": 16,
    "C019Minutos": 0,
    "C019Segundos": 6,
    "C019Milisegundos": 40,
    "C019Resultado": "8",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 4,
    "C019Dia": 24,
    "C019Horas": 7,
    "C019Minutos": 40,
    "C019Segundos": 44,
    "C019Milisegundos": 983,
    "C019Resultado": "2",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 5,
    "C019Dia": 22,
    "C019Horas": 14,
    "C019Minutos": 14,
    "C019Segundos": 5,
    "C019Milisegundos": 733,
    "C019Resultado": "10",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 5,
    "C019Dia": 22,
    "C019Horas": 16,
    "C019Minutos": 46,
    "C019Segundos": 51,
    "C019Milisegundos": 53,
    "C019Resultado": "9",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 5,
    "C019Dia": 23,
    "C019Horas": 9,
    "C019Minutos": 44,
    "C019Segundos": 12,
    "C019Milisegundos": 913,
    "C019Resultado": "10",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 5,
    "C019Dia": 23,
    "C019Horas": 9,
    "C019Minutos": 49,
    "C019Segundos": 13,
    "C019Milisegundos": 946,
    "C019Resultado": "10",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 5,
    "C019Dia": 23,
    "C019Horas": 9,
    "C019Minutos": 56,
    "C019Segundos": 12,
    "C019Milisegundos": 83,
    "C019Resultado": "10",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 5,
    "C019Dia": 24,
    "C019Horas": 14,
    "C019Minutos": 55,
    "C019Segundos": 27,
    "C019Milisegundos": 970,
    "C019Resultado": "6",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 5,
    "C019Dia": 24,
    "C019Horas": 14,
    "C019Minutos": 55,
    "C019Segundos": 36,
    "C019Milisegundos": 140,
    "C019Resultado": "2",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 5,
    "C019Dia": 24,
    "C019Horas": 14,
    "C019Minutos": 55,
    "C019Segundos": 41,
    "C019Milisegundos": 6,
    "C019Resultado": "3",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 5,
    "C019Dia": 24,
    "C019Horas": 14,
    "C019Minutos": 55,
    "C019Segundos": 50,
    "C019Milisegundos": 446,
    "C019Resultado": "4",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 6,
    "C019Dia": 6,
    "C019Horas": 14,
    "C019Minutos": 12,
    "C019Segundos": 20,
    "C019Milisegundos": 820,
    "C019Resultado": "15",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 6,
    "C019Dia": 6,
    "C019Horas": 14,
    "C019Minutos": 17,
    "C019Segundos": 47,
    "C019Milisegundos": 796,
    "C019Resultado": "15",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 6,
    "C019Dia": 6,
    "C019Horas": 14,
    "C019Minutos": 21,
    "C019Segundos": 9,
    "C019Milisegundos": 536,
    "C019Resultado": "19",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 6,
    "C019Dia": 20,
    "C019Horas": 15,
    "C019Minutos": 21,
    "C019Segundos": 7,
    "C019Milisegundos": 140,
    "C019Resultado": "1.1",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 6,
    "C019Dia": 22,
    "C019Horas": 15,
    "C019Minutos": 50,
    "C019Segundos": 57,
    "C019Milisegundos": 590,
    "C019Resultado": "1",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 8,
    "C019Dia": 4,
    "C019Horas": 16,
    "C019Minutos": 37,
    "C019Segundos": 23,
    "C019Milisegundos": 760,
    "C019Resultado": "4",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 9,
    "C019Dia": 14,
    "C019Horas": 9,
    "C019Minutos": 12,
    "C019Segundos": 7,
    "C019Milisegundos": 986,
    "C019Resultado": "2",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 9,
    "C019Dia": 14,
    "C019Horas": 9,
    "C019Minutos": 23,
    "C019Segundos": 5,
    "C019Milisegundos": 596,
    "C019Resultado": "2",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 9,
    "C019Dia": 14,
    "C019Horas": 9,
    "C019Minutos": 41,
    "C019Segundos": 21,
    "C019Milisegundos": 890,
    "C019Resultado": "2",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Determinación de ATP por bioluminiscencia"
}],
"Table1": [{
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 6,
    "C019Dia": 20,
    "C019Horas": 10,
    "C019Minutos": 53,
    "C019Segundos": 32,
    "C019Milisegundos": 820,
    "C019Resultado": "1",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Número más probable Coliformes/cm3"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 6,
    "C019Dia": 20,
    "C019Horas": 15,
    "C019Minutos": 49,
    "C019Segundos": 12,
    "C019Milisegundos": 686,
    "C019Resultado": "0.1",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Número más probable Coliformes/cm3"
}, {
    "C019Anio": 2017,
    "C019Mes": 7,
    "C019Dia": 31,
    "C019Horas": 15,
    "C019Minutos": 53,
    "C019Segundos": 58,
    "C019Milisegundos": 430,
    "C019Resultado": "0",
    "C019NomMaestro": "Número más probable Coliformes/cm3"
}]
```

}

necesito de su ayuda, porfavor ! muy porfavor jaja, ya que los datos pueden ser con intevalos irregulares de tiempo osea que una serie puede tener mas datos que la otra en diferente tiempos. ayudenme porfavor !

el escrip para generar los gráficos seria algo así, lo tome de la documentacion de charts.js ..

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, ],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Reparaciones x dia',
            data: ['0', '4', '1', '3', '1', '0', '0', '1', ],
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,51,0.5)",
            borderColor: "rgba(0,255,51,0.5)",
            fill: false
        }, {
            label: 'Totales',
            data: [0, 4, 5, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 21, 25, 33, 40, 45, 50, 51, 53, 58, 61, 69, 73],
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,153,255,0.5)",
            borderColor: "rgba(0,153,255,0.5)",
            fill: false
        }]
    },
    options: {
        //lineaHorizontal: 55,
        //lineaHorizontalDos: 5
    }      

})
```

Comment: Que tipo de grafica deseas generar? Te lo pregunto para ayudarte de mejor manera. Ya que hay graficas de barras, pie, radar, etc.

Comment: Una grafica de lineas, pero lo particular es que puede que una serie no tenga los mismo datos ni los mismos tiempos que otra, ejemplo una puede empezar el 04/06/ 2018 y terminar el 06/06/2018 y otra puede empezar el 05/20/2018 y terminar el 09/09/2018 ... osea que son intervalos irregulares en tiempo y en datos. agradeceria demasiado tu ayuda.